# Understanding Monomorphic Containers w/ Foldable

Tags: haskell

`snoyberg/mono-traversable`'s [README](https://github.com/snoyberg/mono-traversable/tree/master/mono-traversable#monofoldable) notes

> [MonoFoldable  is the same] as Foldable, but also operates over monomorphic containers.

Please give an example where `Foldable` does not operate over monomorphic containers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`Text`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/text-1.2.2.2/docs/Data-Text.html) is intuitively a container, however it is not polymorphic. Hence

```
Prelude> Data.Foldable.foldr ((:) . fromEnum) [] (Data.Text.pack "blub")

<interactive>:8:28: error:
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘[a0]’
                  with actual type ‘Data.Text.Internal.Text’
    • In the third argument of ‘foldr’, namely
        ‘(Data.Text.pack "blub")’
      In the expression:
        foldr ((:) . fromEnum) [] (Data.Text.pack "blub")
      In an equation for ‘it’:
          it = foldr ((:) . fromEnum) [] (Data.Text.pack "blub")
```

OTOH,

```
Prelude> Data.MonoTraversable.ofoldr ((:) . fromEnum) [] (Data.Text.pack "blub")
[98,108,117,98]
```

Comment: Wow!. I've been trying to get something similar to work for a while. One of my problems was that I was using ord rather than fromEnum. I still don't understand why fromEnum works in your example and ord does not. In case somebody is searching on Data.ByteString.Char8 the example in the answer works with that also

Comment: @GeorgeCo you can't use [`Data.Char.ord`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.17.0.0/docs/Data-Char.html#v:ord) with [`ByteString`s](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/bytestring-0.10.10.0/docs/Data-ByteString-Lazy.html#t:ByteString) because the [`Element`s](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/mono-traversable-1.0.15.3/docs/Data-MonoTraversable.html#t:Element) of these [are `Word8`s, not `Char`s](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/mono-traversable-1.0.15.3/docs/src/Data.MonoTraversable.html#Element). You **can** use it with `Text`, though.

Comment: @leftroundabout thx! That makes sense but I am surprised that the Element of Data.ByteString.Char8 is Word8 not Char. However I see in the doc that there is no Element defined for Data.ByteString.Char8 so perhaps another solution is to maKe a type Instance Element for Data.ByteString.Char8 ? However I should have been looking at ofoldr more closely, as the doc points out: "a monomorphic container can never change its type. So omap is a restricted fmap. However, folding generates a new structure, so we have no such concerns." In any case I should probably be using Text anyways :) Thanks again!

Answer (score 4):

A `Foldable` has kind `* -> *`. Lists, trees, basically anything that can take another type for their element type has that kind. Any instance of `Foldable` must be a type *constructor* , not *a type* , since the class is defined as

```
class Foldable (t :: * -> *) where
   foldMap :: Monoid m => (a -> m) -> t a -> m
                                  --  ^ ^
```

However, `Text`, `ByteString` and other types are clearly a collection of some underlying element type, yet their kind is `*`. They aren't type constructors, they are already types. They don't fit `foldMap`'s type:

```
listLength :: Text -> Int
listLength = getSum . foldMap (const (Sum 1))

textLength :: Text -> Int
textLength = foldMap magic -- will never compile, for no magic
```

Answer (score 1):

I think what's meant here is, that usually when talking about `Foldable` we mean the higher-kinded polymorphic version. I.e. `List` is a `Foldable` for all `a`. So `Foldable` works on types * -> * (also called type constructors).

The `MonoFoldable` type class works on actual types instead. So for example we could write an instance of `MonoFoldable` for something like `Text`.

Answer (score 1):

[`ByteString`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/bytestring) and [`Text`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/text), which can only contain `Word8` and `Char` respectively. Also [unboxed arrays](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/array-0.5.2.0/docs/Data-Array-Unboxed.html) have a restriction on their data type so can't be directly made instances of `Foldable`.

Note however you can trivially make a `Monofoldable` into a `Foldable` just by wrapping it appropriately. My package [`make-monofoldable-foldable`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/make-monofoldable-foldable) does that for you, so for example if you need to pass a `ByteString` to a function that expects a `Foldable` you can just wrap it with [`WrappedMonoFoldable`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/make-monofoldable-foldable-0.1.0.0/docs/Data-MonoTraversable-WrapMonoFoldable.html#t:WrappedMonoFoldable) and then pass it in.

Comment: True. Worth noting however that this GADT wrapper only works for `Foldable`, because that is purely catamorphic. It does not allow you to get around the `MonoTraversable` methods.